# How to change the appearance of a hyperlink-tag but only within a table row

Tags: html

I want to change the appearance of a hyperlink-tag but only when the hyperlink-tag is in a table-row.So not for the entire document, but just for that certain cell. The code below does not work> How can I do that?
Thank you in advanced,

```css
.ms-rteTable-default>tbody>tr>td>a {

}
```

```html
<table class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 50%; height: 1px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableHeaderRow-default">
      <th class="ms-rteTableHeaderEvenCol-default" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100%; height: 1px;">
        <h1>​​​​​</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
      <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="height: 1px;">
        <p>
          <br/>
          <br/>&#160;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Gr. Peter

Comment: can you share also your html? if you want of a certain row then just tr and td might be wrong

Comment: where inside the table is your hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following structure it worked if you have multiple td's and multiple links the best approach would be to give the specific link which you would like to change an id and then change just the color of this specific element by its id

```
#<someid> {
color: red
}
```

```css
.ms-rteTable-default>tbody>tr>td>a {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="ms-rteTable-default">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="www.bla.com" />My Hyperlink</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```